# Access TextField value with EventListener in a function

Tags: actionscript-3, air, touch-event, event-listener

I'm working on an android application with Adobe Air (AS Document class), and I have a function that gets an SQLLite ResultSetb as an array of strings from a SqlLite Database, iterates through the list, creates a TextField for each iteration, and appends them to the stage.

When a user taps on a particular TextField, I want it to be deleted from the database. To capture the event, I implemented TouchEvent Listeners on each of the TextFields, but I can't figure out how to identify which TextField was tapped from the event listener.

My code is:

```
function displayNumbers(allNumbers:Array){
   var y:int=20;
   var telNo:String;
   for(var i:int=0; i<allNumbers.length; i++){
       telNo = allNumbers[i];
       var myText:TextField = new TextField();
       myText.text="text"+i;                    
       myText.addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,doDelNo);                  
       myText.x= 20;
       myText.y=y;
       stage.addChild(myText);
       y+=25;
   }
}
```

Now doDelNo EventListener code is given below:

```
function doDelNo(e:MouseEvent):void{                
   var telNo:String = myText.text; //This is where the problem is
   delNo(telNo);
}
```

The problem is on line 2 of function "doDelNo", because I can't seem to get which instance of TextField was tapped. ActionScript is even throwing an error on line 2 - "access to undefined property myText".

I would be very grateful if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doDelNo(e:MouseEvent):void{   
    var currTextField:TextField = e.currentTarget as TextField; //This is how you get the TextField which was clicked
    if (currTextField != null) {
        var telNo:String = currTextField .text; 
        delNo(telNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Majid. I was also able to use 

    TextField(e.target) 

to retrieve the tapped TextField.